# Adding Containers to Page A from Page B Button Press in Flutter Without Using Lists

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

There is an add button on Page B, onPressed, it should add a new container to add A which can be added using a widget called `BuildCourseContainer`,

**Add Button code:**

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              
        },
```

Now here is something, I dont want to add containers in page A using list so its not an option, is there any other way?

Comment: I believe listview is the better choice, why can't you use a list for your usecase

Comment: Because for this I will have to erase and modify a lot of code as i didn't do it before but I surmise that its th only option left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use List or Array.
the Button should add item to list when it clicked,
then your Page will listen or build item from the List